# Search by string method in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building an ASP.NET Core searching Web API which should return a list of videos who has the same searched QR code (the QR code is a foreign key).

This is the video model:

```cs
public class Video
{
    [Key]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }
    public string Exercice { get; set; }
    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public int Sexe { get; set; }
    public int Categorie { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; } 
    public DateTime DateUpload { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    [ForeignKey ("Machine")]
    public string Machine_Qr { get; set; }

    public Machine machine { get; set; }
    public Coache Coache { get; set; }
}
```

the machine class:

```cs
public class Machine
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Machine_Qr { get; set; }
    public string Machine_Name { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public DateTime InsertedOn = DateTime.Now;
    public List<Video> Videos { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the search controller:

```
[HttpGet("{Qr}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Video>> Search(string qr)
{
    IEnumerable<Video> query = _context.videos.Where(e => e.Machine_Qr == qr);

    if ((query != null))
        return query;
    else
        return Enumerable.Empty<Video>().ToList();
}
```

I tested it and I got an empty list every time.

Comment: You have to materialize your query by adding `.FirstOrDefault()` after the `.Where()` clause.

Comment: @Oliver we can't use .FirstOrDefault() with an IEnumerable method, I need to return a list of videos

Comment: it's a qr code in string format and it's a machine PrimaryKey

Comment: @GazdallahAmira check my answer.

Comment: @Serghei Sorry I tried it but it doesn't worked, because the problem is in my class data annotation

Comment: @GazdallahAmira yes could be you have multiple problems. you can contact me in private messages and  I can help you more

Comment: @Serghei where can I find you in private ?

Comment: @GazdallahAmira exiton3@gmail.com or Facebook Sergey Kichuk location Houston

Comment: Did you try the solution provided? Was the problem resolved successfully?

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute Linq to SQL with Entity Framework you need to update your query like this

```
[HttpGet("{Qr}")]
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Video>> Search(string qr)
 {
     IEnumerable<Video> query = await _context.videos.Where(e => e.Machine_Qr == qr).ToListAsync();


    return query;
```

}

by adding .ToListAsync() it will execute your query transforming into SQL and returning the result

Comment: If you call `.ToListAsync()` you'll never get back `null`. You have to check for an empty collection.

Comment: @Oliver you are right it is just copy paste